# Creating my own tags with preg replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to use add my own tags onto site content so the user can add a specified tag and it replaces with the relevant content. 
for example [company_address]

I'm using preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);

but it fills the page with scrambled text.

```
function search4Tags($content){

    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/[company_name]/';
    $patterns[1] = '/[company_logo]/';
    $patterns[2] = '/[company_address]/';

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = $_SESSION['company_name'];
    $replacements[1] = $_SESSION['company_logo'];
    $replacements[2] = $_SESSION['company_address'];

    return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
}
```

Comment: You didn't escape the `[` and `]` in  your regular expression. Also, you might as well use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the square brackets. They define a character group: any character inside will match.

For example, `/[company_name]/` matches any of the characters `acemnopy_`, so any occurrence of them will be replaced.

From [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) docs:

> If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of `preg_replace()`.

Since you are only replacing constant strings, I'd recommend [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) instead. That assumes the search patterns are plain strings.

Just replace `preg_replace()` with `str_replace()` here and remove the regex slashes.

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '[company_name]';
$patterns[1] = '[company_logo]';
$patterns[2] = '[company_address]';
// identical code omitted 
return str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
```

If you really, *really* need to use `preg_replace()`, escape the brackets with `\`'s.

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\\[company_name\\]/'; 
$patterns[1] = '/\\[company_logo\\]/'; 
$patterns[2] = '/\\[company_address\\]/';
// identical code omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment above, you don't need `preg_replace` for this. `str_replace()` will do everything you need and more. And in exactly 1 line less, too.

E.G.

```
    $this->body = str_replace('[company_name]', '$_SESSION[company_name]', $this->body);
```

Comment: You have extra single quotes there.

Comment: I originally sent the content from the DB to the function should $this->body search the whole page, instead of just returning the revised content.

Comment: @Pietu1998 indeed I do, cheers for pointing that out.
Ajl80 - you can do it whatever way suits you best, this is just an example to show that str_replace is more relevant for you